# How can I open a file that is stored in a virtual machine from host?

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtual-machine, vmware, file-sharing

I'm running Red Hat Linux on VMWare installed on Windows 7 and I want to be able to open a text file that is stored on the VM from Windows. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Not an expert, but if you can access the files inside the VHD file (assuming it was a container like zip) you wouldn't have that problem. Probably virtualization keeps this from happening, due to resource management, although I think Parallels Desktop does use the container approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by doing this:

On the host:
- On VMPlayer go to VM Settings
- Go to the Options tab then Shared Folders
- Pick Always Enabled
- Add a new Folder

Inside the VM:
- Go to /mnt/hgfs/

The files inside the folder will be shared!
Also I think you need root access on VM to copy to the folder.

You might also need to change the Network Adapter to NAT in VM Settings under Hardward tab.

Hope this helps someone!